# Wildcard mapping and static resource conflicts in Spring Boot applications

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have configured the static resource directory in my spring boot application as follows.

```yaml
spring:
  web:
    resources:
      static-locations:
        - "file:${user.dir}/public/"
        - "classpath:/public/"
```

Also, I want to handle all unmatched http requests through a `@GetMapping("/*")` handler.

```java
@GetMapping("/*")
public ModelAndView unmatched(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                @RequestHeader(name = HttpHeaders.IF_MODIFIED_SINCE, required = false) String ifModifiedSince) throws IOException {

    String path = request.getRequestURI();
    
    log.info("path = {}", path);
        
    // ...
}
```

When I request a static resource located in the public directory under the classpath, the request is handled by the `unmatched` handler.

```bash
C:\Users\KevinBlandy>curl http://localhost:8088/favicon.ico
{"success":false,"data":null,"message":"Not Found","code":"NOT_FOUND"}
```

How should Spring Boot be configured to match static resources first? If the static resource does not match, then the `@GetMapping("/*")` handler is matched.